# Share common properties with child objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm pretty sure, that this is an easy question, but I'm stuck right now.
I have the following setting:

```
public ParentClass()
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String PropertyA { get; set; }
    public String PropertyB { get; set; }

    public ParentClass()
    {
        _child1 = new ChildClass1();
        _child1.ID = ID;
        _child1.Title = Title;
        _child1.PropertyA = PropertyA;

        _child2 = new ChildClass2();
        _child2.ID = ID;
        _child2.Title = Title;
        _child1.PropertyB = PropertyB;
    }

    private ChildClass1 _child1;
    private ChildClass2 _child2;
}
```

The parentclass is only there to control the overall behavior, the childclasses do the actual work (each a different part). I want both childclasses to know ID and Title. But Child1 should only know PropertyA, while Child2 should know PropertyB. So every child would have the resulting 3 properties. I could use some dataobjects, but that would lead to calls like _child1.Properties.ID ... 
Is there a best practice or a pattern to solve this kind of a problem?

Comment: What's the real use-case here? Asking how to pass data from `Parent -> Child` is quite a subjective question.

Comment: Your Properties are Fields. Doesn't help in trying to understand this.

Comment: Parentclass creates a control, which consists of 2 subcontrolls (A selection element and a list). The parentclass syncs data between the selection element and the list. So one child represents a selection element, and the other one the list.

Comment: The posted code seems to do the job, so what is the question here?

Comment: I agree with James. The thing that sticks out is that PropertyB and A (which is a field btw) is being duplicated in parent, when you could not bother (just have a getter that checks the child for example). In general, like with ID, you have to keep them in seperate you could modify the getters and setters to tightly couple them rather than hoping they stay the same.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the `decorator pattern`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine. No need to overcomplicate things.

It looks to me that PropertyA and PropertyB could have no backing value for these properties in ParentClass and just get and set the public properties in the Childclasses.

In general it may be best to tightly couple them by having the getters in the parent affect the values in the Childclasses and vice versa, if you expect them not to diverge over their lifetime. An alternative would be to have them all as `readonly`.